# Declare large global array

Tags: c, arrays

What is the best practice for declaring large, global arrays in C?  For example, I want to use `myArray` throughout the application.  However, I lose the use of sizeof() if I do this:

```
// file.c
char* myArray[] = { "str1", "str2", ... "str100" };

//file.h
extern char* myArray[];


// other_file.c
#include "file.h"
size_t num_elements = sizeof( myArray ); // Can determine size of incomplete type.
```

Comment: As a C++ programmer, I'd use `new` or `std::vector`, and not rely on `sizeof()`.

Comment: @muntoo: as a Python programmer, I'd use a `list`. Unfortunately for both of us, the question is about C ;-)

Answer (score 6):

You could define the size:

```
// file.c
char *myArray[100] = { "str1", "str2", ... "str100" };

// file.h
extern char *myArray[100];
```

Then `sizeof` should work, but you could also just `#define` the size or set a variable.

Another options is to count up the length and store it one time in your code...

```
// file.c
char *myArray[] = { "str1", "str2", ... "strN", (char *) 0 };
int myArraySize = -1;
int getMyArraySize() {
   if( myArraySize < 0 ) {
      for( myArraySize = 0; myArray[myArraySize]; ++myArraySize );
   }
   return myArraySize;
 }


// file.h
extern char *myArray[];
int getMyArraySize();
```

This would allow an unknown size at compile time. If the size is known at compile time just storing the constant will save the overhead of counting.

Comment: Best answer hands-down. The `getMyArraySize()` function is really smart. But `#define`ing the length in the header file is the best in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the solution you're looking for:

```
// file.c
char* myArray[] = { "str1", "str2", ... "str100" };
const size_t sizeof_myArray = sizeof myArray;

//file.h
extern char* myArray[];
extern const size_t sizeof_myArray;
```

Comment: You have a bug: `error: array 'myArray' assumed to have one element [-Werror]`; so you'd have to write that first line in the .h file as `extern char** myArray;`instead of `extern char* myArray[];` then use the `sizeof_myArray` variable as required

Comment: @GabrielStaples: Nope. An array of pointers is not a double pointer. If you wrote that declaration in the header, it would mismatch the definition, resulting in UB, and would break catastrophically when code disagreeing on the definition is linker (although thankfully it would be caught if you included the header in the file with the definition). I'm not sure what that warning you got is without more context.

Comment: Yeah I'd need to build a stand-alone minimal program and be sure this was the problem. Was part of a large application. Hopefully will get a chance later to evaluate, test further, and respond.

Comment: You're right that your code does work. I just ran a very basic test with your code above, compiling my test with `gcc -Wall -Werror -std=c99 -I. -o main main.c my_array.c && ./main` and it worked just fine. My error must have been due to something else, as it was in a large code base. I've upvoted your answer now.

Comment: I found my problem: I was missing `extern` in my header file. The array *must* be `extern`, as `extern char* myArray[];`. Without it being extern, you'll get the "one element" error: `my_array.h:7:7: error: array ‘myArray’ assumed to have one element [-Werror] char* myArray[];`. That's confusing to me, as I thought `extern` was the default linkage and that writing it here was optional.

Comment: I read this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-extern-keyword-in-c/, and it refreshed my memory on the usage of `extern`. `extern` is automatically implied for *function* prototypes/declarations and definitions, but for *variables* it is NOT. Therefore, to ensure that the variable is only *declared* in the header, but NOT defined there too (with memory set aside for it here), you *must* use `extern` on all variables that have their definitions elsewhere, such as in this case. Got it--my memory is now refreshed.

Comment: In summary: `extern` is automatically implied on functions, so you can choose to write it or not (it makes no difference), but for variables you must be explicit and use it when you want only a declaration and not a definition, such as for global variables in header files, like this `myArray[]` variable here.

Answer (score 2):

In C you need to store the size separately (possibly in a struct with the array).

An array is nothing more than a block of memory in C, it does not know how much items there are in the array and besides by looking at the type of the pointer, it does not even know the size of a single item in the array<sup>*</sup>.

If you really want to use a global array, than I would recommend something like this:

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 1000
char* myArray[ARRAY_SIZE] = {....};
```

<sup>*</sup>As some people have pointed out, this isn't completely true ofcourse (but still a good rule to program by imho).

Comment: I'd even go as far as saying `const size_t ARRAY_SIZE = 1000;` and `const char * const myArray[ARRAY_SIZE]`...

Comment: @Kerrek: Invalid C. `const size_t ARRAY_SIZE = 1000;` does not create a constant expression and cannot be used as the size of an array with static storage duration.

Comment: @R.: Whoops, I forgot about that. I tend to use VLAs liberally and forgot that they're not in the standard.

Comment: VLA's are in the standard, but they're only valid with automatic storage duration.

Comment: Stack arrays (and global arrays) are _not_ the same as pointers, they _do_ have sizes, you _can_ `sizeof` them. And while the subscript operator can be used with pointers as well as arrays, it isn't the same operation, plain arrays don't have the indirection that pointers have. The reason `sizeof` isn't working for the OP is that the array is defined in a difference source file.

Comment: @Daniel: You are right ofcourse, although I usually prefer the "use this instead" explananation.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether it's a static or dynamic array. Only if it's a static array can you use `sizeof()`.

```
#define MAX_ELE (100)
const static char* MyArray[] = {"str1","str2",....,"str100"}
```

Comment: I suggest keeping @muntoo's formatting and grammar changes :) He's really good at fixing up questions and answers.

Comment: I think you should replace `static` with `automatic`.

Answer (score 0):

In `file.h`, you can put:

```
#include <stddef.h>

extern char *myArray[];
extern const size_t myArray_len;
```

Then in `file.c`, you have:

```
#include "file.h"

char *myArray[] = { "str1", "str2", ... "str100" };
const size_t myArray_len = sizeof myArray / sizeof myArray[0];
```

This way your other modules can refer to `myArray_len`, and you do not need to explicitly write the size of the array anywhere.

(The downside is that `myArray_len` is merely a `const`-qualified variable, not a constant expression, which means that you can't use it to do things like initialise objects with static storage duration, or define the size of non-variably-modified arrays).